# Como passar valor de uma variavel em php pela url?

Tags: php, html, mysql, formulário, crud

Olá, sou programador iniciante em php, estou desenvolvendo em crud e estou com algumas dificuldades.

Tenho uma tabela onde listo todos os meus produtos junto aos produtos tem um botão ACTUALIZAR, quando eu clico neste botão ele me leva para uma página de actualizar e eu quero que o formulário venha já preenchido como os dados correspondentes ao id em que está o botão actualizar

Este é o meu código onde está a tabela (**visualizar.php**)

num_rows;

if($qtd>0){
    print "";

    print "";
        print " ID";
        print "Produto";
        print "Descricao";
        print " Preço";
        print " Ações";
        print "";
    while($rows=$result->fetch_object()){
        print "";
        print "" .$rows->id_produto."";
        print "" .$rows->produto."";
        print "" .$rows->descricao."";
        print "" .$rows->preco."";
        /*print "
        id_produto."'
        ;\">Actualizar
        Eliminar";*/
        print "
        
        
            
        
        ";
        print "Eliminar";
        print "";
        
    }
    print "";   
}else{
    print "Não foram encontrados resultados";
}
?>

============================================================================================

E este é o código do actualizar(atualizar.php)

Actualizar


  
    Formulário de Actualização de Produtos
    
      
       
      
         
        Produto:    
        " class="form-control"/>

```
    <div class="input-box"> 
    <span class="details">Preço:</span>          
    <input id="txtpreco" type="number" name="txtpreco" required="required" 
    placeholder="Digite o nome do preço" class="form-control"/>
    </div>

    <div class="input-box"> 
    <span class="details">Tipo:</span>       
    <input id="txttipo" type="text" name="txttipo" required="required" 
    placeholder="Digite o tipo do produto" class="form-control"/>
    </div>

    <div class="input-box"> 
    <span class="details">Descrição:</span> 
    <input id="txtdescricao" type="text" name="txtdescricao" required="required" 
    placeholder="Digite a descrição do preço" class="form-control"/>
    </div>

    <div class="box-footer">
    <a href="paginaprincipal.html">Home</a>

    <div class="button">
    <input type="submit" name="actualizar" autofocus class= "btn btn-success btn-icon-split" 
    value ="  Actualizar-Dados  ">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

   
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```html
<?php
include("conexao.php");
if(isset($_POST['id_produto'])){
  $id_produto=$_POST['id_produto'];

$query="SELECT * FROM tb_produto WHERE id_produto=$id_produto";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1){
  $rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  $produto=$rows['produto'];
  $descricao=$rows['descricao'];
  $preco=$rows['preco'];
  $tipo=$rows['tipo'];
  
}
}
echo "s".$_POST["txtproduto"];
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
    <title>Actualizar</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title">Formulário de Actualização de Produtos</div>
    <div class="content">
      <form action="visualizar.php" method="POST">
       
      <div class="user-details">
        <div class="input-box"> 
        <span class="details">Produto:</span>    
        <input id="txtproduto" type="text" name="txtproduto" required="required" 
        placeholder="Digite o nome do produto" value="<?php echo $produto?>" class="form-control"/>
        </div>

        <div class="input-box"> 
        <span class="details">Preço:</span>          
        <input id="txtpreco" type="number" name="txtpreco" required="required" 
        placeholder="Digite o nome do preço" class="form-control"/>
        </div>

        <div class="input-box"> 
        <span class="details">Tipo:</span>       
        <input id="txttipo" type="text" name="txttipo" required="required" 
        placeholder="Digite o tipo do produto" class="form-control"/>
        </div>

        <div class="input-box"> 
        <span class="details">Descrição:</span> 
        <input id="txtdescricao" type="text" name="txtdescricao" required="required" 
        placeholder="Digite a descrição do preço" class="form-control"/>
        </div>

        <div class="box-footer">
        <a href="paginaprincipal.html">Home</a>

        <div class="button">
        <input type="submit" name="actualizar" autofocus class= "btn btn-success btn-icon-split" 
        value ="  Actualizar-Dados  ">
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

       
        </form>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

texto em negrito

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Onde está o Input com name="id_produto" para enviar o ID?

Este formulário está enviando pela primeira vez ou está editando?

Se for a primeira vez você precisa receber o
$id_nova = mysqli_insert_id($conexão);

Se for edição, a origem deve vir via POST usando um input com name do id recepetor,
se vier via link ?id_produto=321

você deve colocar a opção se for vazio POST tentar pegar GET
$id_produto= (isset($_POST['id_produto'])) ? $_POST['id_produto'] : $_GET['id_produto'];
if(isset($id_produto)){
$id_produto=$_POST['id_produto']; //remover este

Comment: Não entendi direito

Comment: Estou fazendo edição

Comment: Tem como a gente conversar por whatsapp?